# Load / restore models into tensorflow at specific iteration or checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, restore

I have a model , which I am saving at every 10 iterations . So , i am having following files in my saved directory .

```
checkpoint  model-50.data-00000-of-00001  model-50.index  model-50.meta
model-60.data-00000-of-00001  model-60.index  model-60.meta
```

and so on up to 100 . I have to load only the model-50. Because I have got 
NaN values after 70 iterations. By deafault, when i am restoring the saver will look for the final checkpoint. So, how could I specifically load the model-50. please help, otherwise, i have to run the model gain from scratch, which is time consuming.

Comment: I think you can manually edit `checkpoint` as a very crude hack

Comment: @martianwars - Can you make it more specific ?

Comment: I meant the file `checkpoint` in the save directory

Comment: @martianwars - Yeah , edit the checkpoint file and change model_checkpoint_path to the model which you would like to load. This works. You can give the answer or should I?

Comment: There should be a better way to do this. Let's wait for a day (I'll look later in the day as well). If there is no answer, I'll write this as the answer

Comment: Also, how are you restoring your graph? using `tf.train.Saver.restore()`?

Comment: @martianwars - Cool . Thanks

Comment: @martianwars - Yes , I am using tf.train.Saver.restore()

Comment: @martianwars - That works so great

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using `tf.train.Saver`'s function `restore()`, you can make use of the [`last_checkpoints`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/saving_and_restoring_variables#Saver.last_checkpoints) functions to get a list of all available checkpoints. You will see both `model-50` and `model-60` in this list.

Pick the correct model, and pass it directly to `restore()` like this,

```
saver.restore(sess, ckpt_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if things were different in the past, but at least as of now, you can use [tf.train.get_checkpoint_state()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/get_checkpoint_state) to get [CheckpointState](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_state.proto) proto which contains all_model_checkpoint_paths.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the command shown in most of the tutorials about saving/restoring a model `saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(_dir_models))` the second parameter which you are passing is just a string to model path. This is defined in a [saver.restore](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver#restore) documentation.

> save_path: Path where parameters were previously saved.

So you can path any string there and latest_checkpoint is just a convenient function to extract this path from a `checkpoint` file. Open this file in a notebook and you will see all the model paths available and what is the latest.

You can substitute that path with any path you want. You can get it from that file (either opening it manually or using [get_checkpoin_state](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/get_checkpoint_state) which will programmatically do it for you.